# Implementing addTextChangedListener with RxBinding for currency based calculations

Tags: android, android-edittext, rx-java, reactive-programming, observable

I have an edit text view that is used to calculate currency related stuff.
Edit Text starts at 0.00.
This is for billing purposes in which the vendor inputs the bill amount to be charged to the customer. The user can only input numbers from 0-9 in the edit text box.

If the user inputs 1, it becomes 0.01
If the user inputs 2, it becomes 0.12 and so on

This is the code I have used with TextWatcher which is working perfectly.

```
etInitialOtherBill.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(!s.toString().equals(currentO) && !s.toString().equals("")){
                    etInitialOtherBill.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    String cleanString = s.toString().replace(".", "");
                    double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                    String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));
                    currentO = formatted.replace(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().getCurrency().getSymbol(),"");
                    //new
                    currentO=currentO.replace("\u00A0","").replace(",","");
                    etInitialOtherBill.setText(currentO);
                    etInitialOtherBill.setSelection(currentO.length());
                    etInitialOtherBill.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Double initialMBill, initialOBill;
                if (etInitialMedicineBill.getText().toString().equals("") || etInitialMedicineBill.getText().toString().equals(".")){
                    initialMBill=0.00;
                }else {
                    initialMBill= Double.valueOf(etInitialMedicineBill.getText().toString());
                }
                if (etInitialOtherBill.getText().toString().equals("") || etInitialOtherBill.getText().toString().equals(".")){
                    initialOBill=0.00;
                }else {
                    initialOBill= Double.valueOf(etInitialOtherBill.getText().toString());
                }
                Double discountM =Math.round( initialMBill * 100.0 *discountToConsumer ) / 100.0;
                Double netMBill = Math.round( initialMBill * 100.0 *amountPayable ) / 100.0;
                Double finalBill = netMBill+initialOBill;
                tvDiscountMedicine.setText(df2.format(discountM));
                tvNetMedicineBill.setText(df2.format(netMBill));
                tvFinalBill.setText(df2.format(finalBill));
            }
        });
```

The `afterTextChanged` is to perform some calculations and display it in `TextView`

Currently what I have tried is

```
                RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
                .map(new Func1<CharSequence, CharSequence>() {
                    @Override
                    public CharSequence call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                        //perform calculations as in onTextChanged
                        //This causes the infinite loop. Adding if statements did not solve my problem either
                        return someValue
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                        //If user inputs a number which was formatted, then display it
                        editText.setText(charSequence);
                        editText.setSelection(charSequence.length()
                    }
                });
```

Now this sets the code in an infinite loop, it was avoided by `removeTextChangedListener(this)` . I have tried to use `subscription.unsubscribe()` but this did not get me anywhere.

I'm looking for some guidance with which I can attempt this again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your own CustomEditText and implement there wanted behaviour like in the code below. I hope this helps

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText{

    List<TextWatcher> textWatchers = new ArrayList<>();
    private TextWatcher watcher;

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) {
        textWatchers.add(watcher);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        if (watcher == null) {
            watcher= new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                    for (TextWatcher watcher : textWatchers) {
                        watcher.beforeTextChanged(s, start, count, after);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    for (TextWatcher watcher : textWatchers) {
                        watcher.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    for (TextWatcher watcher : textWatchers) {
                        watcher.afterTextChanged(s);
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        super.removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
        super.setText(text, type);
        super.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
    final CustomEditText editText = (CustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text);
    RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
            .map(new Func1<CharSequence, CharSequence>() {
                @Override
                public CharSequence call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    return charSequence;
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Action1<CharSequence>() {
                @Override
                public void call(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "call: Check infinite loop");
                    editText.setText(charSequence + " " + charSequence.length());
                    editText.setSelection(charSequence.length());
                }
            });
```

Comment: I will try this out tomorrow, sleeping time here. But this is a lot of a code, makes me wonder if using the addTextChangedListener is less of a headache than doing all this.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter, but hacky solution.

```
    { 
    ConnectableObservable<TextViewTextChangeEvent> onTextChanges = 

    RxTextView.textChangeEvents(textView).publish();

    onTextChanges
            .filter(event -> isUser(event.view()))
            .map(this::changeProps)
            .subscribe(event -> {
                textView.setTag(Source.APP);
                setTextProps(textView, event);
            });

    onTextChanges.filter(event -> isApp(event.view()))
            .delay(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(event -> {
        event.view().setTag(Source.USER);
    });

    onTextChanges.connect();
 }

 private boolean isApp(View view) {
    return view.getTag() == null || Source.APP.equals(view.getTag());
 }

 private boolean isUser(View view) {
     return Source.USER.equals(view.getTag());
 }

 private static final class Source {
    public static final String APP = "APP";
    public static final String USER = "USER";
}
```